# RxJava: Creating class instance white running on Observables chain

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a code that uses RxJava in order to parse an XML file.
Whenever a new XML tag is read --> onNext(event_data) is triggered.

I would like to allocate a class entity on "START_DOCUMENT" and fill it with XML parsed attributes.

My problem is that I'm struggling to do it in RxJava flow because it's not part of the Observables chain. I don't know how to allocate the instance so it will be accessible from within the Observables and how to keep the context.

Here is my Code:

[Link to Gist with code sample](https://gist.github.com/shvalb/0022fc6a7c8662b80f1b3631329b89b4)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `scan` or `reduce`. They allow you to carry some state through with each emission and at completion emit that state. `scan` emits the intermediate states and the completion state and `reduce` just emits the completion state. Sounds like you would use `reduce`.